# Show 2-space indents as 4-space in the editor

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, indentation

Suppose a Git repository contains sources with 2-space indents. I want they to be displayed as 4-space indents in VSCode or to be converted to 4-spaces in local repo but pushed back to the server with 2-indents.

Comment: So, the files use spaces for indentation? Neither VSCode nor Git would make this easy. In theory you could modify Git to change indentation the way it changes line endings, or you could modify VSCode to display leading whitespace differently, but as far as I know this cannot be done out of the box. (My suggestion is to learn to live with it… easier to adapt to someone else's coding style when working on their code rather than write scripts to convert between coding styles.)

Comment: @DietrichEpp: you should bring this as answer :-) (upvoted)

Comment: Or you convert in tabs and then everyone could use the setting he want...

Comment: To elaborate on @DietrichEpp solution, the machinery you would need is called "smudge filters" and "clean filters", see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes However, as correctly stated, the fact that you can is not a reason you should...

Comment: I also want this, have you found a way to do this yet?

Comment: no, I've just become accustomed to 2-space indents